# ggplot2: geom areas not appearing

Tags: r, ggplot2

I used a script months ago to build a stacked area chart using ggplot2. I am now trying to re-do it with similar data, but i face the issue where areas are not showing. Prior to that i checked that the dataset could make bar plots.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
SampleID=c("SiteA","SiteB","SiteC","SiteD")
Species1=c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.6)
Species2=c(0.15,0.25,0.35,0.4)
Species3=c(0.05,0,0.4,0.3)
Species4=c(0,0.05,0.05,0.9)
data=data.frame(SampleID,Species1,Species2,Species3,Species4)
mdata=melt(data)
ggplot(mdata, aes(x=SampleID, y=value,fill=variable,order=SampleID))+
geom_area(stat = 'identity',colour='black')
```

[image]

As you see, areas are not appearing. Any would have advices? Thanks!

Comment: Working with ggplot2 `3.1.0` and reshape2 `1.4.3` in the plot area of RStudio. Do you have same view using Zoom ?

Comment: Hi Clemsang i am not sure what is zoom?

Comment: Oh the tool zoom, yes it is the same view (sorry thought you meant another program)

Comment: `geom_area` is only compatible with an numeric x, so if you change your SampleID to some numeric representation, it should work

Comment: Thanks heck1, it indeed worked out! The change however brought a weird behavior from melt, where to solve it i had to specifically tell R the id.vars SampleID and Species1,Species2,Species3,Species4 as measure.vars. In a case where i would have 20+ Species, is there a way to write melt without having to list every Species as measure.vars?

Answer (score 1):

Following comment of heck1,
I replaced character names to numeric. I had to change the melt function to make it work however.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
SampleID=c(1,2,3,4)
Species1=c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.6)
Species2=c(0.15,0.25,0.35,0.4)
Species3=c(0.05,0,0.4,0.3)
Species4=c(0,0.05,0.05,0.9)
data=data.frame(SampleID,Species1,Species2,Species3,Species4)
mdata=melt(data,id.vars = "SampleID", measure.vars = c("Species1","Species2","Species3","Species4"))
mdata=as.data.frame(mdata)
ggplot(mdata, aes(x=SampleID, y=value,fill=variable,order=SampleID))+
geom_area(stat = 'identity',colour='black')
```

[image]

Comment: I know your reviewers asked you to do a plot like this, but I feel this is highly misleading. It assumes a linear relationship between the samples, which does not make sense. The plot would look very different, when you decided to label the sites in any other order.

Comment: The different samples are actual vertical profile of a community gradient in marine sediments (sorry i just kept the story to where the issue i was having). So in reality, Sample 1 is surface sediment and Sample 4 is the bottom of the sediment core. Something I might adapt is to had the real sediment depth instead. I hope saying this makes more sense to use this graph?

Comment: Ah in this case the plot makes totally sense. Indeed, I would switch to the real depth. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Why not using `geom_bar` instead of `geom_area`

```
ggplot(mdata, aes(x=SampleID, y=value,fill=variable,order=SampleID))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',colour='black')
```

produces

[image: GGplot Barchart]

Comment: Hi thothal, yes i had no issue making a bar plot from my data. My situation is more or aesthetics. I have to present several of these graphs in a poster and comments made mentionned that 12 stacked area charts are more easy for the eyes than 12 bar plots.

Comment: Well, `geom_area` is not made for that. What it does, it shades the area on a *continuous* scale from `0` to `y`. Now with *categorical*  data on your x-axis, you would need first to transform your x-scale to a numeric scale.

Comment: Yes, thanks your comment goes in the same way has heck1 and it did work. I was just a bit surprised because 6 months ago i built that script from same data frames and it worked at that time. But i might have to do something i forgot to note. Thanks again!